Ethereum instance not intiialized - call Ethereum.factory first
I am using @metamask/sdk-react in a react project. Below is the code:
import { MetaMaskProvider } from '@metamask/sdk-react';


<MetaMaskProvider
          debug={true}
          sdkOptions={{
            dappMetadata: { name: 'Example' },
          }}
        >

...

When open the UI on chrome, it shows me below error. It says ethereum is not initialised. but how can I initialise it? When open the devtool on chrome, I can see ethereum is available under window object. What else should I do to solve this issue?
Error: Ethereum instance not intiialized - call Ethereum.factory first.


Are you wrapping your <App/> component inside <MetaMaskProvider></MetaMaskProvider> in index.js?

yes, my App is inside the provider

If the code is minimal as of now. Then, can you share the GitHub repo of the same?
